# Extracting Data on Server side php from a Posted Object using RestKit

Tags: php, ios, http, restkit

I posted a object (list) using RestKit to my server api as shown below

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:list path:@"api/lists" parameters:nil
                                            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
        {
            NSLog(@"Success");

        } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }];
```

No i want to know that where in HTTP Post request RestKit has placed the list object, is it the headers or body and if someone would guide me how to retrieve my object using php? i am sending data as serialized json

PS code here executes successfully but no data is added on server because i could not retrieve my object from post request on server.

and my RestKit log is showing this data post request

```
data: {
    listID = 0;
    listName = "new list";
    listSyncStatus = 1;
    tasks = (
    );
})
```

How to i extract this json via php

Previously i was posting data using php curl and retrieving it via fat-free-framework as below

POSTING USING PHP CURL

```
$data = array("listName" => "lorem", "listSyncStatus" => "ipsum");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://mydomain.com/api/lists');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);
```

RETRIEVING 
//routing for post aka new record request

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{       
    $data = json_decode($f3->get('BODY'), TRUE);
    $f3->route('POST /api/lists','Data->AddNewList');
    $f3->set('listName',$data['listName']);
    $f3->set('listSyncStatus',$data['listSyncStatus']);
}
```

Comment: Where is `PHP code to extract POST data` ? Please paste it in your question.

Comment: From a RestKit point of view, the request descriptor and mapping describe how the JSON will be created. And you haven't shown them so... Use Charles to check what is sent.